# Is a point in a topological space connected to itself?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to figure out if some point x in X is connected to itself.  By definition this would mean that there needs to be a continuous function f:[a,b] -> X such that f(a) = f(b) = x, and I think that the function defined f(x_0) = x for all x_0 in X would work since this function is constant and continuous.

I guess my question is, since I can't find it discussed anywhere else in the textbook, is whether or not a point is connected to itself or is there some exception where we don't consider a path to be a path if it does not pass through any other points.

Comment: Yep.  It is connected to itself.

Comment: Yes. There's no exception. Constant functions are always continuous (with any topology on the source and target). I imagine many authors consider this so obvious it does not need to be pointed out, but without constant paths e.g. the fundamental group would fail to have an identity element in general, which would be terrible.